# Best jQuery/Java PHP solution for localhost server - client live chat

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, livechat

I have Apache server with PHP and associated local client PCs in my private network. Can anybody suggest the best chat solution to communicate between client PCs and a server? I am looking for an Ajax/Java solution, like the chat support inside GMail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [JQuery / PHP Chat](http://www.techmixer.com/jquery-php-chat-free-live-chat-script/) which is free and can be integarted into sites.

Comment: yea i got it... is there any way to integrate it like gmail chat??

Comment: unfortunately, you will have to modify it according to your needs. I don't think you will get a fully packaged chat system as per your requirement..

Comment: k.. is there any other solution which don't need a database like your solution??

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider the XMPP service from google app engine for java?

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/

It has very good integration obviously with the rest of google apis and the server can be hosted for free if you're under the quota, or running it on localserver using jetty

Answer (score 0):

Can't do it with Apache. Chat is usually done through a technique called [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), which is not supported by Apache, AFAIK. GMail uses this technique.

Another, less efficient possibility is using polling strategy, which involves a lot of extraneous server-client communication.

Comment: is that meant for ISS or Windows Server or something else??

Comment: Something else - a specifically Comet engine. The requirements are a persistent connection to each client, and that you can respond to an event in one connection instantly in all other connections. It can be rather easy to achieve in node.js or EventMachine, and there are many dedicated Comet Engines.

Comment: Here's an example Comet with PHP, but it fails on event responsiveness (it loops serverside, with a delay, reading a file to see if there is an event): http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start. Since it uses a trick to fake communication between PHP processes, you can do this even on Apache/PHP (as long as you don't mind a slight delay in your chat, or the extra work and extra memory used in the server.)